# Hibernate Criteria query by Example mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

There is only one Envelope object and 2 Invoice object which are mapped by this Envelope.When I try to query with following code, it returns 2 Envelope object which are same. I think there is a problem with my hibernate annotations.Is there any solution?

```
Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
envelope.setPostBox(EnvelopePostBox.INBOX.name());        
List<Envelope> byTemplate = genericDao.getByTemplate(envelope);
```

Envelope entity;

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "envelope", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Invoice> invoiceList;
```

Invoice entity;

```
@JoinColumn(name = "envelope", referencedColumnName = "instance_identifier")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Envelope envelope;
```

My Dao method;

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T> List<T> getByTemplate(T templateEntity) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(templateEntity.getClass());
    criteria.add(Example.create(templateEntity));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T> List<T> getByTemplate(T templateEntity) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(templateEntity.getClass());
    criteria.add(Example.create(templateEntity));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Comment: can you try removing or commenting criteria.add(Example.create(templateEntity));